# Force redirect http to https on IE nort working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, internet-explorer, ssl-certificate

I have setup httaccess file for forcing a redirect to https on all browsers, everything works as expected in all browsers except Internet Explorer 11 version and all other versions of IE,

Here is my htaccess file settings.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.svn
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.git
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?videomerce\.loc/ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?manavault\.pl/ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(.+\.)?manavault\.pl/ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
#RewriteRule api/image/.*$ images/manavault5.jpg [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Unfortunately, these settings do not work on IE,

What am I missing in my codes? any help suggestion will be apreciated

Comment: i think you didn't paste all rules.  did you clear browser cache , IE cache ?

Comment: cache cleared and those are all settings I have

Comment: where is that part that forces https?

Comment: There is no rule that "forces a redirect to https" in those rules, sorry.